# How does a CMS typically structure the schema that holds page information?

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, .net

I am working on a content management system to fit inside my small application. I currently have pages stored in a structure named:

```
Subject
Book
Chapter
Page
```

This works fine but I would like to find a more professional naming for the levels. Can anyone suggest some better sounding groups. Hopefully this question will not be closed as the naming of these key parts of my application is very important to me and I know from past experience that contributors here often have some very good suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Andrew said, it depends on your particular app, but coming from a CMS background, we had something like `Categories` -> `Articles` and `Articles` was self-referencing so you could have child articles ad infinitum.

Queries can be a little funny, but it allows for an infinite layering of articles. Very flexible.

Answer (score 0):

The answer really depends on what makes the most sense for your particular application.

Having said that, I've seen systems where *Pages* are stored in a hierarchy of *Categories*.  So you'd have a top-level collection of categories, each of which contain a collection of pages and another collection of child categories.

That structure is more flexible, and can be managed in two Database tables, with the tradeoff of some complexity in the queries if you're wanting to retrieve more than one level of the hierarchy.